# Not able to change forecast category picklist values

Tags: opportunity, forecast

Need to change the one of the picklist values"Cloased" to "Won" in forecast category field but getting error "Cannot change the status category. This picklist must have at least one value for status category "Closed"."

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem eventually?

Answer (score 2):

This particular issue was difficult to resolve and seems to reflect some buggy behavior on Salesforce's part. In our org, underneath the error you listed was a reference to an Opportunity Record Type. Something in that opportunity record type is broken and can't be updated in an automated way, so I had to:

1. Change the default Opportunity record type on all profiles that was using that one
2. delete that record type and switch all the Opportunity records that were using that record type to use a different one.

That allowed me (finally) to change the ForecastCategoryName

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that at least one of the values in the picklist has the forecast category of closed.

You will need to create a new picklist value and set the forecast category to closed first before you can change the existing value to closed.

Comment: We have changed the value to "Won" in developer sandbox but when we are trying to change in developer pro its trowing error.